# C++ Call the class function with object does not work

Tags: c++

so I make the class which have the function as well inside, and I create the object of the class, and then I create another separate function outside of the class and main function, and I call the function in the class in my another separate function. but it does not work.

```
#include <iostream>

class Hello{
    public:
    void Print(std::string line){
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
};

void myFunction();

int main(){
    Hello World;
    myFunction();
    return 0;
}

void myFunction(){
    World.Print("Hello");
}
```

It is showing this

```
error: 'World' was not declared in this scope|
```

Comment: It's true what the compiler says. `World` was declared in the scope of the `main()` function but you're trying to use it from `myFunction()`. You can either make it global (generally not advised) or pass it as an argument (by value, pointer or reference) to `myFunction()`.

Comment: `World` is crated inside the `main`, and it cannot be accessed outside of it.

Comment: I recommend you to take a look at `scope` in C++.

Comment: `int main() { int x = 10;  myFunction(); }  void myFunction() { std::cout << x; }` -- So you also expected something like this to work?  If you did, C++ does not work this way.  This is basically what you are doing (which is incorrect), using a much more simplified example.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
#include <iostream>

class Hello{
    public:
        void Print(std::string line){
            std::cout << line << std::endl;
        }
};

void myFunction(Hello World);

int main(){
    Hello World;
    myFunction(World);

    return 0;
}

void myFunction(Hello World){
    World.Print("Hello");
}
```

There are two mistakes in your code

1. The non-obvious one, the access label under which you `Print` function is defined is `private` because unless specified the default label is `private` when using `class` (if `struct` is used then default is `public`). For `World` to be able to call `Print` it has to be `public`.
2. `World` is out of scope for `myFunction` because it is defined in `main`. A workaround is to pass the object as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, World is not declared in the scope of myFunction.

Maybe you're after something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Hello{
    public:
    void Print(std::string line){
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
};

void myFunction();

int main(){
    // Hello World;
    myFunction();
    return 0;
}

// add World to global scope
Hello World;

void myFunction(){
    World.Print("Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the variable World is accessed inside myFunction() but the scope is only is only a local variable inside the main function. You can pass the variable in order call the method like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Hello{
    public:
    void Print(std::string line){
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
};
    
void myFunction(Hello* World);

int main(){
    Hello World;
    myFunction(&World);
    return 0;
}

void myFunction(Hello* World){
    World->Print("Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass Word to myFunction so

```
#include <iostream>
class Hello{
    public:
    void Print(std::string line){
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
};

void myFunction();

int main(){
    Hello World;
    myFunction(World);
    return 0;
}
void myFunction(Hello World){
    World.Print("Hello");
}
```